# Using elasticsearch river plugin to connect to a DataSource

Tags: java, elasticsearch, datasource

I have used this command to pull data from an Oracle DB into my elasticsearch index.

```
curl -XPUT "http://10.176.140.209:9201/_river/hed_river/_meta" -d '{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "jdbc": {
    "url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@indl140119.in.oracle.com:1522/in140119",
    "user": "fusion",
    "password": "fusion",
    "index": "highered",
    "type": "courses",
    "sql": "select COURSE_CD,COURSE_TITLE,DESCRIPTION,COURSE_MODE,SCHEDULE_TYPE,CAMPUS,INSTRUCTOR_NAME from  HED_ACAD_COURSE_B"
  }
}'
```

Now instead of using the `DB_URL`,`DB_USER`,`DB_PASSWD` to connect to a DB(as in the above method). I wish to connect to a DB using a `DataSource` Object using JAVA API of elasticsearch. Is it possible?

I mean using something similar to

```
DataSource db;
Connection con = db.getConnection();
```

without extracting the URL,user,password from the `DataSource` Object. Assume I have a DataSource Object with all the required parameters set(URL,user,password)

Comment: you mean client to elasticsearch???

Comment: yes..client to elasticsearch..using client.prepareIndex().setSource()

Answer (score -1):

I have created a [github repository](https://github.com/sidharthancr/elasticsearch-java-client) with working example.. make use of it..

HOpe it helps..!